# Compute the difference of time between Comments and Replies (ChildID, ParentID)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I try to calculate the time difference between two `dataframes` with the same `ID` (`MainID` and `ParentID`) to take into account the connection between comment and response. Thus, one `dataframe` consists of comments with the respective time stamps and a `MainID` and the other `dataframe` consists of answers with time stamps and the `ParentID`, which is identical to the `MainID`. However, in my record, it is possible that a unique comment may contain multiple responses. Therefore it is my goal to calculate the difference of the FIRST answer (or the LAST one) and to write it back in the `dataframe`. However, I have no idea how to realize this and my function doesn't seem to work either.

```
for i in Comments['MainID']:
    commentID = i
    for j in Replies['ParentID']:
        parentID = j
        if commentID == parentID:
            Comments['new'] == Comments['publishedAt'] - Replies['publishedAt']


Comment

   MainID      Message   Published
1  terssfd32   ...       2018-06-25 23:00:00
2  hetasfd2s   ...       2018-06-25 23:10:00
3  eeasdfr3d   ...       2018-06-25 23:20:00
4  ...         ...       ...

Replies

   ChildID    ParentID    Message   Published
1  1a         terssfd32   ...       2018-06-25 23:00:40  
2  2a         terssfd32   ...       2018-06-25 23:05:08
3  3a         hetasfd2s   ...       2018-06-25 23:11:40
4  4a         hetasfd2s   ...       2018-06-25 23:14:30
5  5a         hetasfd2s   ...       2018-06-25 23:16:10
6  6a         eeasdfr3d   ...       2018-06-25 23:22:08


Goal

   MainID        Published             PublishedReply        Diff
1  terssfd32     2018-06-25 23:00:00   2018-06-25 23:00:40   40sec
2  hetasfd2s     2018-06-25 23:10:00   2018-06-25 23:11:40   100sec
3  eeasdfr3d     2018-06-25 23:20:00   2018-06-25 23:22:08   128sec
4  ...           ...                   ...                   ...
```

Comment: How did you calculate the 40 sec of ID `terssfd32`? The `PublishedReply` columns doesnt seem correct.

Comment: Plus where did the timestamps come from suddenly? Your example data needs to be correct for us to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach for this.

Ensure your 'Published' columns are of type `datetime`

```
Comment['Published'] = pd.to_datetime(Comment['Published'])
Replies['Published'] = pd.to_datetime(Replies['Published'])
```

Merge The 2 DataFrames on their corresponding keys

```
df_new = (Comment[['MainID', 'Published']]
          .merge(Replies[['ParentID', 'Published']],
                 left_on='MainID',
                 right_on='ParentID',
                 suffixes=('_comment', '_reply'))
          .drop('ParentID', axis=1))
```

Add the calculated `Diff` column

```
df_new['Diff'] = (df_new['Published_reply'] - df_new['Published_comment']).dt.total_seconds()
```

Sort the DataFrame by `Diff` and drop duplicates. This will keep the 'first' comment.

```
df_new = df_new.sort_values('Diff').drop_duplicates('MainID')

print(df_new)

      MainID   Published_comment     Published_reply   Diff
0  terssfd32 2018-06-25 23:00:00 2018-06-25 23:00:40   40.0
2  hetasfd2s 2018-06-25 23:10:00 2018-06-25 23:11:40  100.0
5  eeasdfr3d 2018-06-25 23:20:00 2018-06-25 23:22:08  128.0
```

If you require the 'last' comment, add `ascending=False` argument to the `sort_values` method

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the code works perfectly! :)

Comment: @Daniel happy to help buddy